# How to use custom defined hues in the palette across the system in Material UI v1?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

It is no secret that v1 theme configuration guide is not easy to understand. I have following palette defined in my web app. My main primary color is '#6699CC' which is used all over the system:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      50: '#e3f2fd',
      100: '#bbdefb',
      200: '#90caf9',
      300: '#64b5f6',
      400: '#42a5f5',
      500: '#6699CC',
      600: '#75a3d1',
      700: '#84add6',
      800: '#93b7db',
      900: '#0d47a1',
      A100: '#82b1ff',
      A200: '#448aff',
      A400: '#2979ff',
      A700: '#2962ff',
      contrastDefaultColor: 'light',
    },
    secondary: {
      50: '#fce4ec',
      100: '#f8bbd0',
      200: '#f48fb1',
      300: '#f06292',
      400: '#ec407a',
      500: '#e91e63',
      600: '#d81b60',
      700: '#c2185b',
      800: '#ad1457',
      900: '#880e4f',
      A100: '#ff80ab',
      A200: '#ff4081',
      A400: '#f50057',
      A700: '#c51162',
      contrastDefaultColor: 'light',
    },
    error: {
      50: '#ffebee',
      100: '#ffcdd2',
      200: '#ef9a9a',
      300: '#e57373',
      400: '#ef5350',
      500: '#f44336',
      600: '#e53935',
      700: '#d32f2f',
      800: '#c62828',
      900: '#b71c1c',
      A100: '#ff8a80',
      A200: '#ff5252',
      A400: '#ff1744',
      A700: '#d50000',
      contrastDefaultColor: 'light',
    },
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiListItemIcon: {
      root: {
        color: 'black',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

1) My first question is how can I use these colors across the system? In previous versions(<=0.19) I was able to access primary color with something like this:`muiTheme.palette.primary1Color`. This is how I tried to extract color from the palette in v1 beta.17 but it does not work:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  rootListItemIcon: {
    color: theme.palette.primary,
  },)}
```

2) How can I extract and use different hues from the palette? For example, how can I use `400: '#42a5f5',` hue defined in the primary palette in my inline style of any component?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:
To access the different hues from different color palette just use:`theme.palette.primary.A200,`

To use specific hues that do not start with letter use this syntax:`theme.palette.primary[400]`